# jdk8 memory tuning with concurrent mark-sweep gc pause issue

Tags: java, garbage-collection

We started with the setting for our JVM as(I inherited this and haven't modified it except trying incremental mode)....

```
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=1
```

We are on two virtual cpus.  I want way more gc pauses or what not rather than a getting behind one that stops the world.  Supposedly CMSIncrementalMode is deprecated though I tried it anyways and it didn't work.

I am trying to work off of 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/cms.html

I am having trouble understand what they mean by duty cycle.  I just want more pauses rather than a big one.  How can I tweak the commands to do this?

Even though the docs state this "Note that the incremental mode is being deprecated in Java SE 8 and may be removed in a future major release", I don't mind using the incremental if I need to for now.

Any ideas on how to configure this or what they mean by duty cycle?

NOTE: We deploy every two weeks so even right after deployment, I prefer not to have big gc pauses as pacing adapts.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Try configuring a larger `young` heap.

Comment: @FranMontero Why would that work?  I want to tell it to gc more often.  If I have a larger young heap, won't it gc less often since it takes longer to hit the full size?

Comment: Minor a Major GC's are Stop Of The World events. So the trick is the balance between many short and few large stops.

Comment: @FranMontero right, so why not just have a smaller cycle.  I think it is related to CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin .  I don't think I should have to resize any young old sizes....just want gc to happen more often.

Comment: GC occurs when young heap become full, so for more GC, you need a smaller young heap in my opinion.

Comment: I took a deeper look.  you are probably right on a larger young heap as I see my old gen doing big swings (and those objects should probably not make it to old gen which may save me from stop the world pauses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use G1GC then you can use `XX:MaxGCPauseMillis` and set a lower value if default value is not desirable for you.